# Unlocking Bootloader Identifier Token Htc desire

Tags: htc-desire, bootloader-lock

[image]I want to unlock my phone's boot loader, but for doing so I need a so called "identifier token". After booting into Fast-boot-mode, I executed
`fastboot oem get_identifier_token` via cmd(adb)
and got

```
FAIL(remote: unknown command)
```

What can I do? Would be great if somone could help!

Comment: what does fastboot devices returns ?

Comment: some code consisting of numbers and letters. I am quite sure the device is recognized

Comment: Yes indeed. Did you enabled USB debugging and oem unlock in the Developers Options?

Comment: Usb debuggin is enabled. But there is no option oem unlocking in the menu.

Comment: But even if I had not turned oem unlocking on, it would give me the token, wouldn't it?

Comment: Of course, you should get the token but it's strange why nothing is appearing.

Comment: it seems the device doesn't know the command. What could be the cause?

Comment: What is tje exact phone model number and Android version?

Comment: Htc desire 626g and android 4.4.2

Comment: The command should work unless you have mistyped the command. Please edit the question including the screenshot of the terminal. Also enable Unknown sources in Settings > Security